# continue the first loop inside a second loop

Tags: java

Was wondering if it was possible to continue a loop inside a loop.

```
for(TestObject object : testObjects)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        if(!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i]))
        // wondering if it's possible to continue to the next test object here
    }
}
```

yes i could use a boolean like this, but was just wondering if it was possible in an other way

```
for(TestObject object : testObjects)
{
    boolean error = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        if(!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i]))
            error = true;
    }
    if(error)
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can send a continue instruction to a particular loop, using a labelled continue. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

```
outer:
for (TestObject object : testObjects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i])) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `break`

What `break` does?

> When the break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next statement following the loop.

```
 for(TestObject object : testObjects)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        if(!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i]))              
          break;        
    }
}
```

Use [`Continue statement`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_continue_statement.htm)

```
     outerloop:
     for(TestObject object : testObjects)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if(!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i]))              
              continue outerloop;        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well i could use that but than it's going to continue with the rest of the code from the first for loop. I just want to continue to the next TestObject and not finsih the current TestObject "loop".

Comment: What do you want? you want to exit the both loops?

Comment: This is actually equivalent to your codes. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, I just saw a comment that there was an option with labelled continue. That was what i was looking for thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I do not know :), downvoter just say why you do that thanks

Comment: @GijsCo if it was what you were looking for mark answer as a correct :)

Comment: @GijsCo your example doesn't show any code after the end of the inner loop.  In that case, there is no more of the TestObject loop to _be_ finished, so breaking out of the inner loop _would_ have the effect of  immediately beginning the next iteration of the TestObject loop.

Comment: Of course not, I was wondering who downvoted you. Probably Kevin Anderson?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a label:

```
outerloop:
for(TestObject object : testObjects)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        if(!object.getArgs[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[i]))
            continue outerloop;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure whether this is the logic you want.